# Convolution matrix - C# - Error with my code :(

Tags: c#, image-processing, matrix, convolution

I would really appreciate some help with this, if anyone would be so kind I would be extremely grateful. I know there is already more efficient code/libraries available on the web that already achieve this, but in self interest and education, I always prefer to write my own functions before-hand to increase understanding, before attempting to make code more efficient. Unfortunately, this one actually has me beat; this should be a function that applies a 3x3 matrix to an image for processing, but the matrix results are incorrect. Any feedback would be great :)

```
public static Bitmap ApplyMatrix(Bitmap sourceImage, double[,] MatrixMaskThreeByThree)
{
    List<pixel> pixelListSource = imageFunctions.GetPixelListFromBitmap(sourceImage);
    List<pixel> pixelListResult = new List<pixel>();
    double factor = 1.0;
    int bias = 0;
    int index = 0;

    foreach (pixel item in pixelListSource)
    {
        double blue = 0.0;
        double green = 0.0;
        double red = 0.0;
        List<pixel>  Matrix3x3GridPixels = FindGridForCentrePixel(pixelListSource, item,sourceImage,index);
        blue += (double) Matrix3x3GridPixels[0].blue * MatrixMaskThreeByThree[2, 2];
        blue += (double) Matrix3x3GridPixels[1].blue * MatrixMaskThreeByThree[2, 1];
        blue += (double) Matrix3x3GridPixels[2].blue * MatrixMaskThreeByThree[2, 0];
        blue += (double) Matrix3x3GridPixels[3].blue * MatrixMaskThreeByThree[1, 2];
        blue += (double) Matrix3x3GridPixels[4].blue * MatrixMaskThreeByThree[1, 1];
        blue += (double) Matrix3x3GridPixels[5].blue * MatrixMaskThreeByThree[1, 0];
        blue += (double) Matrix3x3GridPixels[6].blue * MatrixMaskThreeByThree[0, 2];
        blue += (double) Matrix3x3GridPixels[7].blue * MatrixMaskThreeByThree[0, 1];
        blue += (double) Matrix3x3GridPixels[8].blue * MatrixMaskThreeByThree[0, 0];
        green += (double) Matrix3x3GridPixels[0].green * MatrixMaskThreeByThree[2, 2];
        green += (double) Matrix3x3GridPixels[1].green * MatrixMaskThreeByThree[2, 1];
        green += (double) Matrix3x3GridPixels[2].green * MatrixMaskThreeByThree[2, 0];
        green += (double) Matrix3x3GridPixels[3].green * MatrixMaskThreeByThree[1, 2];
        green += (double) Matrix3x3GridPixels[4].green * MatrixMaskThreeByThree[1, 1];
        green += (double) Matrix3x3GridPixels[5].green * MatrixMaskThreeByThree[1, 0];
        green += (double) Matrix3x3GridPixels[6].green * MatrixMaskThreeByThree[0, 2];
        green += (double) Matrix3x3GridPixels[7].green * MatrixMaskThreeByThree[0, 1];
        green += (double) Matrix3x3GridPixels[8].green * MatrixMaskThreeByThree[0, 0];
        red += (double)Matrix3x3GridPixels[0].red * MatrixMaskThreeByThree[2, 2];
        red += (double)Matrix3x3GridPixels[1].red * MatrixMaskThreeByThree[2, 1];
        red += (double)Matrix3x3GridPixels[2].red * MatrixMaskThreeByThree[2, 0];
        red += (double)Matrix3x3GridPixels[3].red * MatrixMaskThreeByThree[1, 2];
        red += (double)Matrix3x3GridPixels[4].red * MatrixMaskThreeByThree[1, 1];
        red += (double)Matrix3x3GridPixels[5].red * MatrixMaskThreeByThree[1, 0];
        red += (double)Matrix3x3GridPixels[6].red * MatrixMaskThreeByThree[0, 2];
        red += (double)Matrix3x3GridPixels[7].red * MatrixMaskThreeByThree[0, 1];
        red += (double)Matrix3x3GridPixels[8].red * MatrixMaskThreeByThree[0, 0];
        blue = factor * blue + bias;
        green = factor * green + bias;
        red = factor * red + bias;

        if (blue > 255)
        { 
            blue = 255; 
        }
        else if (blue < 0)
        { 
            blue = 0; 
        }

        if (green > 255)
        { 
            green = 255; 
        }
        else if (green < 0)
        { 
            green = 0; 
        }

        if (red > 255)
        { 
            red = 255; 
        }
        else if (red < 0)
        { 
            red = 0; 
        }
        item.blue = (byte)blue;
        item.green = (byte)green;
        item.red = (byte)red;
        pixelListResult.Add(item);
        index++;
    }
    Bitmap resultBitmap = imageFunctions.GetBitmapFromPixelList(pixelListResult,
    sourceImage.Width, sourceImage.Height);
    return resultBitmap;
}


public static List<pixel> FindGridForCentrePixel(List<pixel> source, pixel centrePixel, Bitmap image, int currentIndex)
{
    List<pixel> PixelGrid = new List<pixel>();
    int rowEnd = image.Width-1;
    pixel X00 = (currentIndex - rowEnd) - 1 > -1 ? source[(currentIndex - rowEnd) - 1]: source[currentIndex];
    pixel X01 = (currentIndex - rowEnd) > -1 ? source[(currentIndex - rowEnd)] : source[currentIndex];
    pixel X02 = (currentIndex - rowEnd) + 1 > -1 ? source[(currentIndex - rowEnd) + 1] : source[currentIndex];
    pixel X10 = currentIndex-1 > -1? source[currentIndex - 1]: source[currentIndex];
    pixel X11 = source[currentIndex];
    pixel X12 = currentIndex +1 < source.Count -1 ? source[currentIndex+1] : source[currentIndex];
    pixel X20 = (currentIndex + rowEnd) - 1 < source.Count-1? source[(currentIndex + rowEnd) - 1] : source[currentIndex];
    pixel X21 = (currentIndex + rowEnd) < source.Count - 1 ? source[(currentIndex + rowEnd)] : source[currentIndex];
    pixel X22 = (currentIndex + rowEnd) + 1 < source.Count - 1 ? source[(currentIndex + rowEnd) + 1] : source[currentIndex];
    PixelGrid.Add(X00);
    PixelGrid.Add(X01);
    PixelGrid.Add(X02);
    PixelGrid.Add(X10);
    PixelGrid.Add(X11);
    PixelGrid.Add(X12);
    PixelGrid.Add(X20);
    PixelGrid.Add(X21);
    PixelGrid.Add(X22);
    return PixelGrid;
}

public class pixel
{
    public int pixelX = 0; //pixel co-ordinates in the image
    public int pixelY = 0;

    public byte blue = 0; //between 0 and 255 (RGB settings)
    public byte green = 0;
    public byte red = 0;
    public byte alpha = 0; //transparency
}
```

Comment: have you set break points throughout the code and used the debugger to check the values ..?

Comment: Yup - the grid co-ordinates returned from the find grid function seem right

Comment: You are overwriting the values in `item` such that later executions do not have access to the original values.

Comment: Awesome - exactly that Nico - thanks. Such an obvious mistake too, cant believe that I missed it.